# Asynchronously fire a shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a `Timestamp` component that should update every 6000 milliseconds. Here is the base:

```
class Timestamp extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    timestamp: PropTypes.date.isRequired
  };
  render() {
    const { timestamp } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="timestamp">
        {moment(timestamp).fromNow()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have read through the [lifecycle of a react component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), and it looks like [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) is what I want -- however, there does not seem to be an asynchronous way to apply this. Eg:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  const { timestamp } = this.props;
  this._timer = setInterval(() => {
    // need to update
  })
}
```

How should this be accomplished in react?

Comment: To do that, you should put `setInterval(()` in `componentDidMount(){}` and have `setState()` called every 6s. Calling `setState()` will re-render you component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case better start timer in `componentDidMount`, and in `setInterval` call `setState` which triggers re-render

```js
class Timestamp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this._timer = null;
    this.state = { timestamp: Date.now() };
  }
   
  componentDidMount() {
    this._timer = setInterval(() => this.onChangeTimestamp(), 6000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._timer);
  }
  
  onChangeTimestamp() {
    this.setState({ timestamp: Date.now() }) 
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="timestamp">
        { new Date(this.state.timestamp).toString() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timestamp />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering only React, updating your component can be done either using `setState()` or using [forceUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) (that you should avoid).

In both cases, this is not in `shouldComponentUpdate` that this should be done. Put `setInterval(()` in `componentDidMount(){}`